# How can I make an existing maven project as a part of multi module maven project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

My goal is to turn an existing maven project (char-counter) into a module of my multi-module maven project. How can I do this? I use Eclipse 4.16.0.

Here is the structure of my projects.
[image]

Comment: Can you share the structure of your existing project?

Comment: I edited my question and added a screenshot. Does it help?

Comment: First you have to remove the source which is located in `multi-module-project/src` ? ...then you can move your `char-encounter` project into the directory structure under `multi-module-project` afterwards you have to add an module entry in the pom.xml file which is located in `multi-module-project/pom.xml` and change/create a parent entry in `char-encounter` project pom file ...

Answer (score 0):

You can include the `sub-modules` inside your parent maven project in following way.

Inside your multi-module-project `pom.xml`

```
<modules>
    <module>char-counter</module>
</modules>
```

See here: [Maven Multiple module](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to convert your char-counter project to multi-module-project.

You need to have following in your multi-module-project pom.

```
<groupId>com.parent</groupId>
 <artifactId>multi-module-project</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
 <module>Anagram<module>
 <module>Calculator<module>
</modules
```

And then in Anagram project's pom :

```
<parent>
        <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>multi-module-project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

     <groupId>com.child</groupId>
     <artifactId>Anagram</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

And in Calculator project's pom:

```
   <parent>
        <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>multi-module-project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

     <groupId>com.child</groupId>
     <artifactId>Calcultor</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Also you need to add dependency of one module to other,in which you want to use the code from other module and then you need to deploy the artifact(module) which has dependency included in it and has starting point to run (like main).

Comment: @IceTeaGreen, Does it answer your question? If yes, please accept the answer,so that it  will help someone else as well in future and if no,please let me know your doubts.